# Динамическое создание категорий на сайте

Tags: php

Есть страница, на которой выводятся категории допустим статей. И когда мы переход в какую-либо категорию, там выводятся статьи, связанные с этой категорией.
У меня такие мысли: "Создаются 2 таблицы, одна со списком категорий, другая со списком статей". И вот здесь возникают 2 вопроса.
1) Как связать две таблицы между собой
(То есть при добавлении статьи мы выбираем ей уже существующую категорию, в которой она будет выводиться и она появляется на странице нужной категории)
2) И как динамически создавать php страницы (То есть если мы добавили категорию, то под нее должна создаться страница на которой будут выводиться статьи этой категории)
Если что-то непонятно написал, пишите в комментарии, объясню, что хотел донести.

Comment: 1) в базе foreign key, в php/html выводите `<select>` со списком категорий в любой форме как вам нравится; 2) Вопрос непонятен, все страницы на php пишутся одинаково как обычно

Comment: я бы вам порекомендовал прочитать сначала какие-нибудь вводные книги по вэб-программированию, базам данных и пхп. вероятно все это устроено не так, как вы себе представляете

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо. Второй вопрос вот о чем. Можем ли мы средствами php создать php файл. Ну вот как мы просто на компьютере создаем файл. И можете посоветовать где мне на эту тему почитать или посмотреть.

Comment: Можете,  но это вам не надо. А надо вам вернуться на комментарий 2 к этому вопросу.

Comment: Файлы php создаются абсолютно так же, как и любые другие файлы. Однако желание сделать это как правило указывает на недостаточность знаний и необходимость вернуться к комментарию 2 к этому вопросу

Comment: Ну да) Так и есть. Я понял)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Как связать две таблицы между собой

Допустим, у вас есть таблица категорий `category` со следующими полям:

- `id` - уникальный авто-инкремент (число автоматически возрастает на
  единицу с каждой новой записью)
- `name` - название статьи

А также есть таблица статей `articles` со следующими полями:

- `id` - уникальный авто-инкремент
- `category_id` - ID категории к которой относится статья
- `name` - Название статьи
- `text` - Текст статьи

Как вы можете заметить, у каждой записи (и у статей, и у категорий) есть свой уникальный ID, при этом в каждой статье есть ID категории. Таким образом вы привязываете статью к конкретной категории. Разумеется в целях упрощения здесь были показаны только самые базовые поля (чтобы просто показать суть), и вовсе не затронута тема foreign key'ев, связей и их видов. Это просто минимальный пример структуры БД, где логически такая связь реализована.

> И как динамически создавать php страницы (То есть если мы добавили категорию, то под нее должна создаться страница на которой будут выводиться статьи этой категории)

Все немного не так. Создавать php страницу под каждую категорию вовсе не нужно. Ваш php скрипт (или скрипты) должен (или должны) формировать нужный HTML, который вы покажете пользователю, учитывая параметры которые приходят в запросе.

Например, у вас есть 3 категории, и вы хотите чтобы у вас на странице где-то выводилось меню с этими 3-мя ссылками, где каждая будет вести на отдельную страницу категории. Сколько нужно php файлов чтобы сделать такое? Конечно это зависит от архитектуры вашего приложения, но в целом, можно обойтись даже одним.

- В вашем единственном .php файле, который называется, допустим, index.php, происходит запрос к базе и получение списка категорий (со всеми полями, id'ом, названием и так далее)
- Ваш php скрипт формирует HTML кусок с меню, где на каждую категорию приходится своя ссылка (`index.php?category=1`, `index.php?category=2` и так далее) и вы этот кусок HTML'а где-то выводите (делаете echo)
- Пользователь кликает по ссылкам этого меню, и переходит ***на всё тот же index.php***, но уже с параметром category, который вы можете вытащить из `$_GET` массива.
- В вашем `index.php` скрипте, вы обнаруживаете что поступил параметр category, и если это так - находите все статьи, у которых `category_id` соответствует тому, что пришло в запросе. Используя полученные из БД данные формируете HTML с этими статьями и выводите его пользователю.

Примерно так обычно работают веб-приложения на PHP. Разумеется это все очень упрощенный пример и есть еще много нюансов (с которыми, если займетесь всем этим, вы столкнетесь), но думаю для стартового "толчка" такого понимания будет вполне достаточно.

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Это просто топовый ответ. То, что я и хотел)